# Uniformly continuous semigroups are analytic

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, semigroups-of-operators

*Reposting from stackexchange.*

I know that every analytic  $C_0$-semigroup is differentiable and then every differentiable semigroup is norm continuous.

I want to know where uniform continuity fits in the above picture.

My intuition is that since the generator of a uniformly continuous semigroup is bounded, it is of the form $(e^{tA})_{t\geq 0}$ for some bounded operator $A$, and being the generalization of "exponential" it should certainly be analytic (or at least differentiable). On the other hand, the implication "uniform continuity implies analyticity" seems questionable.

Comment: The answer is yes and you find it in any book on semigroups. In few words we may define $e^{zA} $ by a power series.

Comment: Something is wrong in your premisses, since $C^0$-semigroup are not necessarily norm-continuous.

Comment: @DenisSerre But I never said that they are?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thanks!

Comment: @Guest You say that a $C^0$-sg is differentiable, and that a differentiable sg is norm-continuous. Thus you imply that a $C^0$-sg is norm-continuous. Don't you ?

Comment: @DenisSerre No, I say an "analytic" $C_0$-semigroup is differentiable.

Comment: @Guest. An analytic semi-group is a sg defined for $z$ beloging to an open sector of the complex plane. This does not imply that the sg be norm-continuous. Example: the heat semi-group.

Comment: @DenisSerre I follow the standard monograph of Engel and Nagel where Diagram II.4.26 says that every analytic $C_0$-semigroup is (immediately) norm continuous.

Comment: @DenisSerre he talked about "$C_0$-sg" not just "sg"..

Comment: @Guest You are not quoting correctly, in fact, uniform continuous isn't the same as immediately uniform continuous, the same for diffierentiable.